# Ignore specific warnings in AUCTeX

Tags: auctex, compilation

I'm going through a LaTeX document fixing a bunch of broken references. I use AUCTeX. I ran `TeX-toggle-debug-warnings` to make `TeX-next-error` jump to warnings about references.

However, my document also has [other warnings that I don't care about right now](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292410/babel-and-index-both-redefine-markboth-and-markright). So I compile, I press `` C-x ` ``, and each time I get these two warnings before the interesting ones.

How can I tell AUCTeX to ignore specific warnings? (This question isn't about the `\markboth`/`\markright` warnings in particular, I expect to enter a regexp somewhere.) Either on a document by document basis, or in my init file.

Comment: Do you know you can see the list of all errors and warnings with `M-x TeX-error-overview RET`, instead of going through a series of ``C-x ` ``?

Comment: @giordano I didn't, thank you. But actually I can't, because that command is not available on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04, AUCTeX 11.87). In any case, I want something really straightforward to go to the first “interesting” warning — I basically have a cycle of `C-c C-c RET C-x \`` fix repeat.

Comment: Full parsing of the whole output log is what has been implemented in AUCTeX 11.88 (making it possible to create `TeX-error-overview`).  Why can't you install AUCTeX via ELPA?

Comment: Anyway, a possible way to do what you want is to redefine `TeX-parse-error' to ignore unwanted warnings.  But note this and many other functions related to error and warning reporting have been rewritten since AUCTeX 11.87, then answering a question specific to a code four-year-old is somewhat a waste of time.

Comment: @giordano I'd accept an answer that requires 11.88. But answering a question about the version of a package that's in current distributions (Debian stable, Ubuntu LTS) isn't a waste of time.

Comment: ELPA makes AUCTeX provided by distros somewhat useless and prone to be outdated ;-)  For AUCTeX 11.88 one can remove undesired entries from `TeX-error-list` after `TeX-parse-all-errors`.  I can't prepare an answer right now, I'll try to do that later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is now present in development version of AUCTeX and will be available in the next ELPA release (presumably 11.89.2) and in the next official stable version (presumably 11.90).  There are two options controlling the behavior: `TeX-ignore-warnings` and `TeX-suppress-ignored-warnings`.  With the former you set the regexp matching warnings to be ignored, with the second you actually tell AUCTeX to hide the warnings.  For your case you'd have to add the following code to your init file

```lisp
(setq TeX-ignore-warnings
      "LaTeX Warning: Command \\\\mark\\(both\\|right\\)  has changed."
      TeX-suppress-ignored-warnings t)
```

You can show or hide these warnings with <kbd>C-C C-t C-x</kbd> (`TeX-toggle-suppress-ignored-warnings`).

In the error overview you can open with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `TeX-error-overview` <kbd>RET</kbd>, it's possible to toggle visibility of such ignored warnings with <kbd>x</kbd>.  BTW, you can also toggle visibility of all bad boxes and generic warnings with <kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>w</kbd>, respectively.

---

In previous versions of AUCTeX, the best way to accomplish what you ask is be to hack into `TeX-parse-error` and skip warnings to be ignored there.  But this function was fairly large and is changed fairly often, then a redefinition would overwrite these changes, so I advise against redefining `TeX-parse-error`.

Instead, if you have AUCTeX 11.88 or later you can hack into `TeX-parse-all-errors`: after parsing the whole compilation log remove the unwanted warnings.  Add the following code to your init file

```lisp
(setq mg-ignored-warnings
      "LaTeX Warning: Command \\\\mark\\(both\\|right\\)  has changed.")
(defun mg-remove-ignored-warnings (&rest args)
  "Remove unwanted warnings from `TeX-error-list'."
  (let ((list TeX-error-list)
    entry new-list)
    (while (setq entry (pop list))
      (unless (and mg-ignored-warnings
           (string-match mg-ignored-warnings (nth 3 entry)))
    (push entry new-list)))
    (setq TeX-error-list (reverse new-list))))
(advice-add #'TeX-parse-all-errors :after #'mg-remove-ignored-warnings)
```

You only have to set `mg-ignored-warnings` to a regexp matching warnings you want to skip and you're done.

Please note also that since version 11.88 it's available a nice formatted list of all errors and warnings reported in the compilation log, <kbd>M-x</kbd> `TeX-error-overview` <kbd>RET</kbd>, that makes navigating through such messages much easier.

Comment: [This sort of problem](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20330/after-upgrading-auctex-latex-mode-is-unusable-invalid-function-tex-auto-add) is why I don't like installing packages outside my distribution. Given the time testing your answer will have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: @Gilles the feature you asked is now available directly in AUCTeX `;-)`.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of feedback — I was working on other things, and now that I'm coming back to this task [I realize that I'm still running the system-provided version of AUCTeX](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20995/detect-whether-a-package-auctex-is-installed-from-emacs).

Comment: For example I want to hide this warning: `You should put a space in front of parenthesis. [36]` (`flycheck-warning`) how could I add it into the  `TeX-error-list`? @giordano