# After upgrading AUCTeX, (La)TeX mode is unusable (invalid-function TeX-auto-add-type)

Tags: auctex, upgrade

I installed AUCTeX through the package interface. This pulled version 11.89 from ELPA. Before that, I was running a version of AUCTeX provided by my operating system (Ubuntu 12.04), which is 11.87. After restarting Emacs to ensure I was using the new version, switching to (La)TeX mode fails with the error

```
File mode specification error: (invalid-function TeX-auto-add-type)
```

I have no reference to `TeX-auto-add-type` in my init file, so what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation**: In version 11.87, `TeX-auto-add-type` was a function. In version 11.88 (since [commit f4d3f2840e8f448a329b223c081bce556eb6ca67](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/tex.el?id=f4d3f2840e8f448a329b223c081bce556eb6ca67), `TeX-auto-add-type` became a macro. My understanding is that during the installation of the newer version in a live Emacs, the function was loaded, and the byte compiler picked up the function. After restarting Emacs, there was no function, only a macro, but the bytecode refered to the function, hence the error. It's unclear to me whether this is due to a bug in AUCTeX or a lack of robustness in byte compilation in Emacs in general.

**Fix**: to recompile the bytecode now that the function is no longer present in memory. This can be done by uninstalling the `auctex` package and reinstalling. Alternatively, remove the bytecode files `~/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.89.1/*.elc` (adjust for your AUCTeX version) (open the directory in Dired, `% m \.elc RET D yes RET`) and recompile them (`M-0 M-x byte-recompile-directory` — you need the prefix argument 0 to recompile all the files even though the no `.elc` file is present).

**Note**: This problem can be avoided by not performing the package installation in a live Emacs, but in a dedicated instance. Generally speaking, performing package installations in an instance of Emacs just for that task is safer.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue, `TeX-evince-dbus-p: Invalid function: dbus-ignore-errors`. Recompiling `auctex` using your method works for me!