# (require 'flx-ido) fails, but "M-x flx-ido-mode" succeeds

Tags: package, libraries, require

I installed the `flx-ido` package from MELPA, and added the following two lines of code to my .emacs file.

`(require 'flx-ido)
(flx-ido-mode 1)`

Emacs startup fails with the following error:

`File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, flx-ido`

Yet, after I see the error, I can type `M-x flx-ido-mode` and the flx-ido-mode operations start to work fine. So the flx-ido files must have been loaded.

I don't understand how this behavior is possible. Does anyone have some ideas that I might try to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs initializes the package system *after* loading `.emacs`, not before. (See [Startup Summary](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html#Startup-Summary) and [Packaging Basisc](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Packaging-Basics.html#Packaging-Basics).) I think the reason is to allow you to configure (or even disable) the package loading process from `.emacs`.

You can add `flx-ido-mode` to [`after-init-hook`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Init-File.html#index-after_002dinit_002dhook). Or you can follow the [officious advice](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21024) which is to call `package-initialize` from your init file. After that point, you can load packages. `flx-ido-mode` should be autoloaded, there's no need to load the package explicitly.

```
(package-initialize)
…
(flx-ido-mode 1)
```

Comment: Gilles, thank you so much for explaining the order of package-initialize. Sure enough, it was located AFTER flx-ido-mode in the load sequence. I have moved the package-initialize (and melpa paths, etc) earlier in my load sequence, and now everything works fine. Excellent answer!